# Highlight autocorrected words

Tags: keyboard, auto-correct, spell-check

I've been using my Android phone for typing more lately, and decided to turn on autocorrect to try it out (it was off by default). While it's handy, [as the entirety of the internet already knows](http://www.damnyouautocorrect.com/) it's frustrating to have an autocorrected word change to something completely different, and then have it be a total pain in the ass to try and get it to type what I meant to type.

For example, I was searching for 'Wifi Direct' recently, but it kept being changed to something like 'whifflefart' or something else completely wrong. Tap-holding the autocorrected word didn't give me any options, and I eventually had to type 'direct', move the cursor back, and type 'wifi', so it wouldn't consider the two words as one word. This is the most egregious one, but it's happened fairly frequently, especially for unknown terms.

The solution I'm imagining is having each autocorrected word highlighted similar to how urecognized words are, with the word being squiggly-underlined in blue or green or something. This would help you notice words have been autocorrected so you can check them before sending, and then you could tap-hold the word to get a list of other corrections or have it revert to what you typed.

I've tried to search for an app or utility that does something vaguely like this, but haven't found anything remotely relevant. I'm not really sure what this type of app would be called, though, which hasn't helped in my search... if it even exists in the first place!

I'm using Android 4.1.2, rooted, and the default keyboard.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such app. But you can still solve your problems. There are many keyboards available to try out whose auto-correction features are totally acceptable.

You can try these from Play Store:

1. [Swift Key](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey)
2. [Fleksy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.syntellia.fleksy.kb)
3. [Swype](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nuance.swype.trial)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the standard AOSP/Google keyboard, any auto-corrections can be immediately undone by pressing the backspace key.